# d3-js: scale time over sec, min, hour, day, month and year

Tags: d3.js

how can i create a time scale over seconds, minutes, hours, days, months and years. in my code i get a second line when the seconds overlap.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the 0 line
var valueline0 = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.value0); });

// append the svg object to the id="chart" of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 75 )
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("/trace/O00.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.value0 = +d.value0;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.value0); })]);

  // Add the valueline0 path.
  svg.append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("d", valueline0);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

O00.csv:

```
date,value0         
2020-07-14T14:03:51,35.66
2020-07-14T14:04:01,23.56
2020-07-14T14:03:11,32.64
2020-07-14T14:03:21,22.55
2020-07-14T14:03:31,28.60
2020-07-14T14:03:41,38.70
2020-07-14T14:03:51,35.66
2020-07-14T14:04:01,23.56
2020-07-14T14:04:11,21.54
```

[chart with 2lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0T86.jpg)

the second line starts with the 7th data record (2020-07-14T14:03:51,35.66) because the seconds (51) from the 1st data record (2020-07-14T14:03:51,35.66) are repeated.
Thanks in advance, Onka

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? It isn't clear. From the code, the input, and the output chart, it is exactly as I would expect. How do you want it to be different?

Comment: there should only be one line. continuously with the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is "only one line". You have Dates with multiple values. If you don't want one of the values, then you have to remove that value from your dataset, by filtering the data in some way.

If you want to remove the extra datapoint you'll have to figure out which one is the correct value. For instance if we say, "Let's use the max value", convert this code:

```js
  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.value0 = +d.value0;
  });
```

To this

```js
// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    d.value0 = +d.value0;
});

const dataMap = {};
let dupCount = 0;;
data.forEach((d, index) => {
    if (!dataMap[d.date]) {
        dataMap[d.date] = true;
    } else {
        // remove the duplicate from the CSV
        data.splice(index - dupCount, 1);
        dupCount++;
    }
});
```

Alternative, and much simpler, would be to first filter the data from the CSV using the csv parser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser and then passing that to the `.data(filteredCsvData)` function rather than using the builtin `d3.csv()` which doesn't contain what you need.

Comment: thanks for your reply Warren. no records should be filtered. rather, the scaling should take into account not only the seconds but also the minutes, hours, days, months and years and the line should be continued. The line should show the time span from the first to the last data record.

Comment: I don't really understand what that means, can you draw a picture of what you expect this to look like?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was due to the non-consecutive records in the csv file. if the sequence is correct, everything works as desired! done! thanks for all...